# If $\varphi\in L^p(\mu)'$ and $\varphi(1_B)=\int_Bf\:{\rm d}\mu$, can we deduce $f\in L^p(\mu)$?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, radon-nikodym

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a finite measure space, $p\ge1$ and $\varphi\in L^p(\mu)'$. Note that $$\nu(B):=\varphi(1_B)\;\;\;\text{for }B\in\mathcal E$$ is a well-defined real-valued measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ with $\nu\ll\mu$. Hence, $$\nu=f\mu$$ for some $f\in L^1(\mu)$ by the Radon-Nikodým theorem.

> Does it somehow follow from $\varphi\in L^p(\mu)'$ that $f\in L^p(\mu)$?

Comment: Your question is unclear. $\varphi \in L^p(\mu)'$ means (by Riesz representation), that there exist $f\in L^{p}(\mu)$  s.t. $\varphi (g)=\int_{E}gf\,\mathrm d \mu$ for all $g\in L^q(\mu)$ (where $1/p+1/q=1$)

Answer (score 0):

It's standard that $L^{p}(\mu)'$ is isomorphic to $L^{q}(\mu)$, where $q \geq 1$ is the dual exponent satisfying $q^{-1} + p^{-1} = 1$.  Specifically, the map $\Phi : L^{q}(\mu) \to L^{p}(\mu)'$ given by
\begin{equation*}
[\Phi(f)](g) = \int_{E} g(x) f(x) \, \mu(dx)
\end{equation*}
is linear, continuous, and bijective.  This is proved in textbooks on real analysis, often under the name "Riesz Representation Theorem."

Hence, in your case, we can find $f \in L^{q}(\mu)$ so that $\varphi = \Phi(f)$.  Notice $f$ need not be in $L^{p}(\mu)$ (if $p > 2$).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the $L^p$-duality. But one is usually first proving this claim for finite $\mu$ using precisely the measure $\nu$ I've described in the question. The crucial question is how we deduce from here that there is a representative in $L^p(\mu)$ of $\varphi$.

Comment: The representative is in $L^{q}(\mu)$, not $L^{p}(\mu)$.  The proof in Rudin, *Real and Complex Analysis* uses exactly your measure $\nu$...